# Windows Server 2019 Best Practices Analyzer - Error is Fixed but a new scan still displays same error. What to do?

Tags: windows, active-directory, hyper-v, windows-server-2019, best-practices

**Server OS:** Windows 2019

**Roles:** Hyper-V, DC, DNS, etc. (2 vms on Hyper-V **RDS** vm and **DC** vm)

The old IT team had this configuration now I want to change it to best practices.
BPA scan on **Server Manager > Local Server** shows some errors/warnings but even after fixing those items a new scan of the BPA shows the same things as **not fixed**. I checked many times and confirmed that the actual fixes are in place.

**Two of the errors are below:**

*Error - Virtual machines should be backed up at least once every week.*

*Error - Domain controller X.local must have "Access this computer from the Network" granted to the appropriate security principals.*
Any ideas? Is the only option to exclude it from the list?